# How to update the value of slider and switch when get back from presentModalViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have accounts which they have some settings attributes. As settings there are value of `UISlider` and value of `UISwitch`. When i run the application it works fine i can display the last value from `NSUserDefaults` because viewDidLoad method works. My application has a tab bar controller by the way. So when i switch tabs it works fine too because i can get the values of switch and slider and update them in viewWillAppear method. But in my setting switch, i present a view which there are user list in it, so the user can select any account. When i get back from presented view i can't update the values of switch and slider. I need a trigger method to update their values. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this are the 3 apple ways to do it:

```
1) Delegation
2) NSNotificationCenter
3) KVO
```

However for your particular case a modal view, the delegation pattern is the one Apple recommends, and is the one I would recommend as well.

It requires a bit more coding than the other 2 options though.

First you have to declare the protocol in the view you are presenting modally:

```
in your .h

@protocol MyProtocol;

@interface MyClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<MyProtocol> delegate;

@end

@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject>

-(void)updateValues:(NSArray *)values;

@end
```

Then before presenting the modal view modally from the original view controller simply set the delgate like this

```
myModallyPresentedController.delegate = self;
```

Then have your presenting view controller adopt the protocol

```
in your .h

MyPresentingViewController : UIViewController <MyProtocol>

in .m

//Implement method:

-(void)updateValues:(NSArray *)values {
   //Update Values.
}
```

Finally when user presses "Done"

you can call

```
[delegate updatedValues:myValues];
```

And update accordingly.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks but i have the values attributes already in my appDelegate object as appDelegate.activeAccount.switchValue and .sliderValue so i need to viewController is aware of my values. I can update when program starts with viewDidLoad by user defaults. But when i get back from presented view values doesn't change because there is no method to update them. Even if i wrote the update method. By the way there are delegation between my two viewControllers already.

Comment: @M.SalihKocak I am not sure I am understanding the problem correctly, but if there is delegation already why not create the method and send to the delegate. Alternatively you can use the NSNotificationCenter and send a message to the observers to update themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this a while ago and basically just paste it into all of these questions. BTW if anyone has suggestions that would make this easier to understand/better I would love to hear them.

You can use delegates to pass information around between classes; this is especially useful for cases where you want to pass information when a method is used.

```
Delegates

//In parent .m file:
//assign the delegate
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueName"])
    {
        childController *foo = segue.destinationViewController;
        foo.delegate = self;
    }

}

//implement protocol method(s):
- (void) methodName:(dataType*) dataName
{
    //An example of what you could do if your data was an NSDate
    buttonLabel.titleLabel.text = [[date description] substringToIndex:10];
}

//In parent .h file:
//import child header
#import "ChildName.h"

//indicate conformity with protocol
@interface ParentName : UIViewController <ChildNameDelegate>

//In child .h file
//declare protocol
@protocol ChildNameDelegate
- (void) methodName:(dataType*) dataName;
@end

//declare delegate
@property (weak, nonatomic) id<ChildNameDelegate> delegate;


//In child .m file
//synthesize delegate
@synthesize delegate; 

//use method
- (IBAction)actionName:(id)sender 
{
    [delegate methodName:assignedData];
}
```

Comment: Why prefer `unsafe_unretained` to `weak` which is dangling-pointer-immune?

Comment: The delegate protocol methods are from before ARC

Comment: So it's a historical accident that you could fix now by using weak, right?

Comment: Probably, I haven't looked up the difference between `unsafe_unretained` and `weak` in-depth yet. I guess using `weak` would let me check if a delegate was `nil` if it had been deallocated and handle the error more appropriately than a hard bad access crash.

Comment: You don't even have to check if it's null. Your actionName method will run fine whether it is or not. That's the point: weak pointers become nil instead of dealloced objects which make your code explode.

Comment: Right, but if the delegate is `nil` and I'm trying to send data to it it's a problem. The description of `weak` made realize that it provides a built-in way to check if the objects are there versus `unsafe_unretained` which looks the same no matter what.

Comment: Exactly, you can check for nil, but you cannot check for a dangling pointer without blowing up.

Comment: @Yar took me forever to remember what post this was. Anyway, `weak` can't be used for iOS 4 deployment targets (or snow leopard) but `unsafe_unretained` can. Just had an issue from that. Of course, in the code above I'm using storyboard methods sooo there's no reason to worry about iOS 4. Just though I'd let you know ;) I was wondering why they kept `unsafe_unretained` around, and I guess it`s for legacy support.